# generating protected/expandable predicates in expl3

Tags: expl3

working on an expl3 package, I got a request to make 'expl3 predicate functions' either expandable or protected (https://github.com/alceu-frigeri/starray/issues/1).

specifically, I got stuck at:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \__starray_if_free:n #1 {T, F, TF}
  {
    \prop_if_exist:cTF {#1}
      { \prg_return_false: }
      { \prg_return_true: }
  }
%\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \__starray_if_free:n {e} {T, F, TF}

\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \starray_new:n #1 {T, F, TF}
  {
    \__starray_if_free:nTF {\l__starray_prefix_tl #1 _def_prop}
      {
%        \__starray_new:e {#1 }
%        \__starray_base_new:ee {#1}{#1} % TODO: might be incomplete !!!
        \prg_return_true:
      }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
 this ~  is ~ just ~ a  ~ test 
\end{document}
```

IF I replace {T, F, TF} by {p, T, F, TF} latex complains, for example,
 `Predicate '\starray_if_free_p:n' must be expandable.`

As I understood (from interface3.pdf), given that \prop_if_exist:cTF is fully expandable, I thought that, at least `\__starray_if_free_p:n` would also be.

What I missing here (expandability) or what can be done ?

Thanks For any help !

Comment: You've used `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn` not `\prg_new_conditional:Npnn`, so you've explicitly said you want protected code

Comment: that's the problem.  I had, originally, used just \prg_new_conditional:Npnn
All fine for my 'intended use', but an user tried to use the predicate version in a \bool_if
and, it resulted in a low level TeX error... 
with the \prog_new_conditional, I can have {p, T, F, TF} but it's kind of moot because the _p (predicate) one fails to be expanded.
Trying to define with \prog...protected, it doesn't even allows to define a predicate version.
there is  a way around it? or it is just the case 'the core functions' (not just those above) aren't expandable, so no chance of having a predicate one?

Comment: BTW, that's (above) is just a 'minimum example' that reproduces the kind of error I got into. The real package code makes extensive use of expl3 non-expandable functions. so, no real hope of having a true fully expandable version of most package functions...
My question would, in fact, be: There is a way (work around) that allows to define a 'expandable predicate conditional' when the underlying code isn't expandable ?

Comment: "I had, originally, used just \prg_new_conditional:Npnn All fine for my 'intended use', but an user tried to use the predicate version in a \bool_if and, it resulted in a low level TeX error..." Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: @muzimuzhi
I have, but not a small one... anyway, at github, https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1202
it's kind of dead end. the real code makes extensive use of expl3 non-expandable code (based on properties, sequences, token lists) so the functions are inherently non-expandable, therefore, it's not possible to have a predicate version of them (even less a non-protected, at it).
edit: OH. I just noticed you are the one replying at github...

Comment: One thing you misunderstood: The functions that aren't expandable can't be provided as predicates. So for these you have to drop the `p` (there is no possibility to provide them for unexpandable stuff). Those functions that are expandable can retain the `p`-variant. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the Github-issue. Also sorry that I can't answer you on Github currently, will do so as soon as possible.

Comment: For those functions that only use expandable stuff you can use `\prg_new_conditional:Npnn <name> <args> { p, TF, T, F } { <code> }` for the others use `\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn <name> <args> { TF, T, F } { <code> }`. (that's basically what @JosephWright's first comment says, just not this explicit)